# is this service doing something wrong?

Tags: jquery, web-services, jsonp, getjson, jersey-2.0

I want to build a web service that is able to send back a `JSONP`

My service looks like the following

```
@GET
@Path("user/{id}")
@Produces({"application/javascript", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@JSONP(callback= "eval",queryParam = "callback")
public Response getUser(@PathParam("id") int id, @Context HttpHeaders headers
) {
    //for (MediaType mediaType : headers.getAcceptableMediaTypes()) {
    //    System.out.println(mediaType);
    //}

    User u = UserDao.instance.getModel().get(Integer.toString(id));
    Response res = Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(u).build();
    return res;

}
```

Is it right? or wrong?

when I access the service with Jquery (I'm a newbie to jquery atm) I get an error, the following is the code that I use to access the service.

```
  jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8084/simple-service/webapi/myresource/user/1",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(results) {
            alert("Success!");
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I have two different error messages:

- from firefox:  "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement", with "1:1" in place of line number. By clicking 1:1 a pop up shows up and displays the following `{"id":"1","name":"Brittni","surname":"North"}`
- form chrome:
  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ", shows the same pop up of firefox with the same content.

It looks like is missing the name of the callback fucntion? :S

Can you help me spotting out what I am doing wrong? :D thanks for helping!

Comment: click on the error, this will expand the results and show you the line number, looks like you have not included all the code on your page

Comment: @davethecoder thanks for suggestion. I added the information but I can't spot out why this is happening, if I cut and paste the url from firefox console and I run the request using postman it will return correctly.. Any suggestion on how to make this work? Thanks..

Comment: remove dataType or change to json  rather than jsonp

Comment: I already tried, isn't working as well.. 
I'm not sure if is the call to the service or the service itself doing wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok guys! I solved it by my self, here is the solution if you are interested at it.

Here is the code of the service if you want to reach it when you are not in the same origin:
set the headers over the response, additionally add the `@Jsonp` annotation.

```
 @GET
    @Path("user/{id}")
    @Produces({"application/javascript", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @JSONP(callback= JSONP.DEFAULT_CALLBACK,queryParam = JSONP.DEFAULT_QUERY)
    public Response getUser(@PathParam("id") int id, @Context HttpHeaders headers
    ) {
        User u = UserDao.instance.getModel().get(Integer.toString(id));
        Response res = Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(u).build();
        res.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        res.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
                "true");
        res.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        return res;

    }
```

For Cross-domain call, use the built in flags in the ajax request. The other fields (like dataType) will be automagically filled by jquery in a smart fashion.

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8084/simple-service/webapi/myresource/user/" + e.data.id,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(results) {
            console.log("Success!");
            $this.trigger("populate", [results]);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```